# Elastic search Garbage Collection taking more time due to aggregation queries

Tags: elasticsearch-ruby

Elastic search **spikes** and **request queuing** are frequently happening whenever **heavy aggregation** is running.Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: You'll need to optimize your aggregations to use less resources.

Comment: but my requirement is to do heavy aggregations for making filters dynamic.Is there a way?